# How to tell if all characters in a string are same

Tags: jquery

I want to know if all characters in a string are same. I am using it for a Password
so that i tell the user that your password is very obvious.
I have crated this

```
$(function(){
    $('#text_box').keypress(function(){
        var pass = $("#text_box").val();
        if(pass.length<7)
            $("#text_box_span").html('password must be atleast 6 characters');
        else
            $("#text_box_span").html('Good Password');
    });
});
```

How can I achieve the same characters?

Comment: In these cases, it's better to test for what you want than to try and test for all the things you don't want. That is to say test that `pass` is at least seven letters and numbers.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
/^(.)\1+$/.test(pw) // true when "aaaa", false when "aaab".
```

Captures the first character using regex, then backreferences it (`\1`) checking if it's been repeated.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bj4sM/) that [Brad Christie posted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619528/how-to-tell-if-all-characters-in-a-string-are-same#comment7815073_6619547)

Answer (score 2):

This would also work:
http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/SVet6/

```
function SingleCharacterString (str)
{
    var Fletter = str.substr(0, 1);
    return (str.replace(new RegExp(Fletter, 'g'), "").length == 0); //Remove all letters that are the first letters, if they are all the same, no letters will remain
}
```

In your code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#text_box').keypress(function(){
        var pass = $("#text_box").val();
        if(pass.length<7)
            $("#text_box_span").html('password must be atleast 6 characters');
        else if (SingleCharacterString(pass))
            $("#text_box_span").html('Very Obvious.');
        else
            $("#text_box_span").html('Good Password');
    });
});
```

Comment: Using regex, then exploding it in to this...beast of a function...makes me cry a little on the inside.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote in pure javascript:

```
 var pass = "112345"; 
    var obvious = false; 

    if(pass.length < 7) { 
       alert("password must be atleast 6 characters");
    } else { 

    for(tmp = pass.split(''),x = 0,len = tmp.length; x < len; x++) {
        if(tmp[x] == tmp[x + 1]) {
           obvious = true; 
        }
    }

    if(obvious) { 
       alert("your password is very obvious.");
    } else { 
      alert("Good Password");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one-liner:

```
str.split('').every((char) => char === str[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one allows you to also specify a particular character to check for.  For example, are all characters the letter 'Z'?

```
function same(str,char){
    var i = str.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (str[i]!==char){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
// same('zzza','z'); returns false
```